# Given a star's luminosity and a distance from said star, how can I get lux?

Tags: luminosity

Today I wish to know how bright interstellar space is by calculation. I have a dataset of 1000 stars which includes their luminosities. But how do I get illuminance (lux) from luminosity (watts) from a distance R? I am seeking a formula so I can put it into my MATLAB script. Dankeschön!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the irradiance (flux in W/m$^2$) is as easy as assuming the source emits isotropically and dividing the luminosity in Watts by $4\pi R^2$, where $R$ is the distance to the source in metres.

However, the illuminance in lux is defined in terms of a particular spectral distribution of light and how bright it appears to the eye. For example, full sunlight exposure at the Earth corresponds to a flux of about 1360 W/m$^2$, but an illuminance of about 100,000 lux.

Without a detailed model of the spectrum of each star perhaps the best you can do is work out the flux in W/m$^2$ and then multiply by a conversion factor of $\sim 70$ to get the illuminance in lux.

More formally, the illuminance will be given by
$$I =\frac{638.002}{4\pi R^2}\int^{\infty}_{0} L(\lambda) \phi(\lambda)\ d\lambda\ , $$
where $L(\lambda)$ is the spectrum of the star in Watts per nm and $\phi(\lambda)$ is the so-called [standard luminous efficiency or luminosity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficiency_function) of the eye per nm, normalised to unity at 555 nm.

Comment: Does a value of 7.217432e-32 lux seem better? My stars are an average of 5.5 LY from other stars.

Answer (score 1):

The [luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity) is the rate at which visible light energy is emitted by the star. It is usually assumed that this light energy is emitted uniformly in all directions.

The [illuminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminance) at distance $R$ is the rate at which light energy crosses a unit area at distance $R$. Since the luminosity (in lumens) is spread uniformly over an area of $4 \pi R^2$, you can find the illuminance (in lux or lumens per square metre) by dividing the luminosity by $4 \pi R^2$.

Note that this does not take into account any absorption of visible light by, for example, dust or gas. Also note that if the luminosity values that you have are in watts rather than lumens, they may be measuring the radiant power of each star - the power it emits across the whole electromagnetic spectrum - rather than its luminous power - the power it emits in the visible light part of the spectrum.

Comment: I ran the calculation. I'm getting 1.820786e-33 lux, which makes sense because stars are so very far apart. Now I know how to draw a scene in my comic!

Comment: @Ylahris If you got that number by dividing the power by $4\pi R^2$, it is about two orders of magnitude off. Irradiance ($\text{W/m}^2$) and illuminance ($\text{lx}$) are closely related, but the latter is weighted by the luminosity function. See ProfRob's answer.